# cin - reading plus/minus as char

Tags: c++, input, cin

I have a problem with the input of my program. It is supposed to input a mathematical expression e.g. `( x + 3 + ax - 5)`. All items are separated by a white space.

The way I handle this: first I try to read an integer with `cin >> number`. If it fails, I try to read an array of chars. I then check if this is an operator (`+,-,*,/,( or )`) - if not, then this must be a variable.

The problem I experience is with the signs of plus and minus. The `cin`, while reading an integer, seems not to print an error while reading + or -. Is there any way of making this work the way I intend? 
Thanks in advance and here is my code fragment:

```
int number; char * signs = new char[3]; char signsBeginning[3] = "aa"; 
signs = signsBeginning;
while(#endexpression){ 
     cin >> number;
     if(!cin){
       //not a number
       cin.clear();
       cin >> signs;
       //handling the input
     }else{
       //number
     }
}
```

EDIT: Forgot to add : I can't use strings.

Comment: If it didn't read a minus sign, it would take a lot more work to handle negative numbers being input.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be possible for you to just use `std::getline()` to read the whole string, and then parse it?

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

// Parse the read line ...
```

Comment: Im sorry, I forgot to add I mustn't use strings as it is my school assignment

Answer (score 1):

If the numeric input fails, the input file position may have been incremented so you can't go backwards.  You may have to build your numbers.

Since you are not allowed to use `std::string`, I recommend that you read one character, process the character then read another.

You can build an integer by converting the character to internal representation, multiplying existing number by 10 and adding the new "digit":

```
char c;
cin >> c;
if (isdigit(c))
{
  unsigned int digit = c - '0';
  number = number * 10 + digit;
}
```